# Use localised version of link based on user's country

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I have the following in my code:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/">Amazon</a>
```

This is fine for me because I am in the UK and expect to see amazon.co.uk.

What can I do to ensure the link goes to the user's country instead of an arbitrary one?

For example, if the user is in Germany, how can I ensure the link leads to `amazon.de`?

Comment: You can not ensure that. If the user clicks on amazon.co.uk, he will see amazon.co.uk, unless amazon decides to redirect to the german site. What you can do, is check the country from where the visitor comes from and if he is from germany, replace the content inside the href attr to amazon.de

Comment: You are going to need a listing of appropriate domain names and a service that lets you detect the origin of their ip address like http://www.maxmind.com/ (please note that this is very time-consuming to make)